# Restrict multi browser login to SharePoint for same user

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have a requirement that need to restrict multi browser login with same user into SharePoint. We have 2 AD, 1 for external user and 1 for internal user. Our SharePoint site was integrated with AD. When the user accessing the portal, they will be redirected to AD home page to choose the AD. Once they choose the AD option, they will be redirected to appropriate AD login page. After validate, they will be redirected to SharePoint Home Page.

We need to implement once the user session established, we should not allow the user login from another browser. Please guide how to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write some javascript in the masterpage that identifies the tab and makes sure there is only one session open by window or tab id.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896160/any-way-to-identify-browser-tab-in-javascript

And: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70170/restricting-user-to-one-open-tab-in-browser

Comment: And to prevent using another Browser? quote: "*we should not allow the user login from another browser.*"

Comment: every tab/window will have it's own window/tab id. You could restrict based that. Just a theory, no POC. Also if you wanted to restrict Firefox/Chrome and only allow IE, you can also do that using JavaScript.

Comment: And the scenario where 2 devices are you used? Only option is the Server records who is logged in... and you will run into the challenge.. How does the server know a user is no longer logged in?

Comment: Another device would deem another session. There is server side code to retrieve the session or token, but not sure about retrieving using javascript. That would be quite difficult to manage in my opinion.

Comment: We theorized about storing the session in the users Profile. But we never could put a sure way of the logout-challenge on the whiteboard.. In the end the customer did not want to pay for the hours.. and said "well.. it isn't really a problem"... ah yes.. customers with requirements..

Comment: I'm thinking maybe delete/exipre all the cached tokens if a user logs on another machine. Or there can be a backend custom cache per local IP.

Comment: Yes.. a lot of tech Server Side.... and then you move to SharePoint Online..

Comment: Well you sure can't do anything about it in SPO

Comment: Hi, Is there is any way to retrieve the logged-in users session. I'd like to validate the session token if user logged-in from different browsers. For ex, if user access the portal through IE, I need to store user session in cookie and if user access through Firefox, I need to validate the existing user token and restrict it. But web is stateless, for every request from different browsers, it will be create a new session cookie and not validate it.